# ie FIELDSET tag Automatically the same as the window size but not content,and content overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
    <legend>overflow test <a href=#1 onclick="insertDiv();">insertDiv</a></legend>
    <div id="box">
        <div style="width:5000px;border:1px solid orange;">init div is overflow </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<script>
function getObj(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function insertDiv() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.style.width = '10000000px';
    div.style.border = '1px solid red';
    div.title = 'it is overflow';
    getObj('box').appendChild(div);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*it will show like that*

```
----
|  |
__________________ this is the insert div
|  |
|  |
----
```

What can i do?

this link is the bug test blog article ,it have all bug images.
[bad layout img](http://hi.baidu.com/qidizi/blog/item/b25d452b71c414261e308976.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, here's the code I added some HTML to show the outline of the containing div. Also I added some content to the div being inserted via innerHTML.

overflow test insertDiv
        
            init div is overflow

```
<script>
function getObj(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function insertDiv() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.style.width = '10000000px';
    div.style.border = '1px solid red';
    div.title = 'it is overflow';
    div.innerHTML = 'test content for insert div';
    getObj('box').appendChild(div);
}
</script>
```

This is what it looks like after I click on the 'insertDiv' link:

[image]

Unless I misunderstood the question. From what I understood you wanted a div to be inserted within the 'box' div and for the 'box' div to automatically grow to contain it.

Here is a jsFiddle so that you can review it and play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/gxhrx/

Comment: it is bad layout too;the images link http://hiphotos.baidu.com/qidizi/pic/item/40405e31e5dde711eddcebbba7efce1b9d16611c.jpg     |  http://hiphotos.baidu.com/qidizi/pic/item/126630fc1a4c510f98d14a576059252dd42aa509.jpg ,if it have not `<!DOCTYPE html>`,the layout is  good on my ie 9;

Comment: Hey @qidizi I added the images to the jsFiddle. I tried it on IE 9, 8, 7, Firefox, and Chrome. Firefox had a problem with the really big width 10000000px so I made it smaller. But otherwise it worked. jsFiddle uses <!DOCTYPE html> so I don't know why it works for me. Can you include a screenshot of what it looks like for you.

Comment: this is the screenshot img link:http://hiphotos.baidu.com/qidizi/pic/item/72334beb76c6a7efb10b036bfdfaaf51f3de6671.jpg;if the ie doc mode is set to "quirks",the every view mode setting is good layout;

Comment: I think the images you are sending are being blocked they all look like this to me: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/same.gif/

Comment: [link](http://hiphotos.baidu.com/qidizi/pic/item/72334beb76c6a7efb10b036bfdfaaf51f3de6671.jpg) this link is ok;

Comment: sorry but that link shows me the same thing, it appears the images from that site are being blocked.

Comment: sorry,maybe must login to see the images,[this link is my blog article](http://hi.baidu.com/qidizi/blog/item/b25d452b71c414261e308976.html),you can see all bug test images in it;